# Get property's value of date

Tags: c, wmi

I'm currently writing a C program which have to do WMI query.
I can issue a query without trouble, but it begin to be really hard when it come to retrieve property's value from the VARIANT variable.

I have a huge switch case, and for each case I just want to wprintf the value (the final purpose is to retrieve the value in a wchar_t string).

So far, for the integer type, it wasn't so difficult, but for the datetime type, I can't have something at all.

Here's the example i'm working on (there are no function check for the sake of lisibility, but I do it :

```
typedef struct cpwmi {
    IWbemLocator         *locator;
    IWbemServices        *services;
    IEnumWbemClassObject *results;
    IWbemClassObject     *result;
} cpwmi_s;

void CpWmi_Constructor(cpwmi_s *self)
{
    self->locator = NULL;
    self->services = NULL;
    self->results = NULL;
    self->result = NULL;
}

void CpWmi_Destructor(cpwmi_s *self)
{
    if (self->result) {
        self->result->lpVtbl->Release(self->result);
    }
    if (self->results) {
        self->results->lpVtbl->Release(self->results);
    }
    if (self->services) {
        self->services->lpVtbl->Release(self->services);
    }
    if (self->locator) {
        self->locator->lpVtbl->Release(self->locator);
    }
}


void CpWmi_MinimalExample(cpwmi_s *self)
{
    // Connection
    CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_WbemLocator, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, &IID_IWbemLocator, &self->locator);

    BSTR ressource = SysAllocString(L"ROOT\\CIMV2");
    self->locator->lpVtbl->ConnectServer(self->locator, ressource, NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, &self->services);
    SysFreeString(ressource);

    // Issue WMI query
    BSTR query = SysAllocString(L"SELECT ReleaseDate FROM Win32_BIOS");
    BSTR language = SysAllocString(L"WQL");
    self->services->lpVtbl->ExecQuery(self->services, language, query, WBEM_FLAG_BIDIRECTIONAL, NULL, &self->results);
    SysFreeString(query);
    SysFreeString(language);

    // Go to first result
    ULONG   count = 0;
    self->results->lpVtbl->Next(self->results, WBEM_INFINITE, 1, &self->result, &count);

    // Get propperty's value
    BSTR    propertyName = SysAllocString(L"ReleaseDate");
    VARIANT propertyValue;
    CIMTYPE propertyType;
    self->result->lpVtbl->Get(self->result, propertyName, 0, &propertyValue, &propertyType, 0);
    wprintf(L"%s: ", propertyName);

    if (propertyValue.vt != VT_NULL && propertyValue.vt != VT_EMPTY) {
        switch (propertyType) {
            /* Many case here */
        case CIM_DATETIME:
            wprintf(L"%f", propertyValue.date);
            break;
        }
    }
    VariantClear(&propertyValue);
    wprintf(L"\n");
}

int main(void)
{
    cpwmi_s wmi;

    CpWmi_Constructor(&wmi);

    // initialize COM
    CoInitializeEx(NULL, COINIT_MULTITHREADED);
    CoInitializeSecurity(NULL, -1, NULL, NULL, RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT, RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, NULL, EOAC_NONE, NULL);

    CpWmi_MinimalExample(&wmi);

    CpWmi_Destructor(&wmi);

    // unwind everything else we've allocated
    CoUninitialize();

    printf("Stop\n");
    getchar();
    return;
}
```

I expect to have something like

ReleaseDate : 20140401000000.000000+000

but I end up with

ReleaseDate : -92559592126069970772275711289628980735378270670621907468943360.000000

I must misread msdn documentation or don't know how to search/read, because up to this point, I have no idea how to do that in C !
I'm also worried about CIM_REFERENCE_TYPE, CIM_OBJECT_TYPE and the alike.

Is there anyone who have a hint or know to do that ?

Comment: `CIM_DATETIME` is a string ([one of two fixed-length formats specific to _WMI_ and _CIM_](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa387237(v=vs.85).aspx)).  I'm not fluent in `c` however in scripting, use the `SWbemDateTime` object to convert these to regular dates and times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`propertyValue.date` is `double`, it needs `"%g"` print format, but it's probably not valid. Try `bstrVal` value instead:

```
case CIM_DATETIME:
    //wprintf(L"%g\n", propertyValue.date);
    wprintf(L"%s\n", propertyValue.bstrVal);
    break;
```

<sup>Note, in debug mode you can move the cursor over `propertyValue` and it should show the values contained in `propertyValue`</sup>

Comment: The heck ... Thanks, I guess I will just have to do as you say : see in propertyValue with a debugger (I can't believe I didn't think of that, I have a long way to go).